# How to use groups parameter in PyTorch conv2d function

Tags: convolution, pytorch

I am trying to compute a per-channel gradient image in PyTorch. To do this, I want to perform a standard 2D convolution with a Sobel filter on each channel of an image. I am using the [`torch.nn.functional.conv2d`](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.1.12/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) function for this

In my minimum working example code below, I get an error:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

filters = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1,1,3,3))
inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1,3,10,10))
out = F.conv2d(inputs, filters, padding=1)
```

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight[1, 1, 3, 3], so expected
>   input[1, 3, 10, 10]  to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

This suggests that `groups` need to be 3. However, when I make `groups=3`, I get a different error:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

filters = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1,1,3,3))
inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1,3,10,10))
out = F.conv2d(inputs, filters, padding=1, groups=3)
```

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 4: out of range at
>   /usr/local/src/pytorch/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensor.c:440

When I check that code snippet in the THTensor class, it refers to a bunch of dimension checks, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

What does this error mean? How can I perform my intended convolution with this `conv2d` function? I believe I am misunderstanding the `groups` parameter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to apply a per-channel convolution then your `out-channel` should be the same as your `in-channel`. This is expected, considering each of your input channels creates a separate output channel that it corresponds to.

In short, this will work

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

filters = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3,1,3,3))
inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(1,3,10,10))
out = F.conv2d(inputs, filters, padding=1, groups=3)
```

whereas, filters of size `(2, 1, 3, 3)` or `(1, 1, 3, 3)` will not work.

Additionally, you can also make your `out-channel` a multiple of `in-channel`. This works for instances where you want to have multiple convolution filters for each input channel.

However, This only makes sense if it is a multiple. If not, then pytorch falls back to its closest multiple, a number less than what you specified. This is once again expected behavior. For example a filter of size `(4, 1, 3, 3)` or `(5, 1, 3, 3)`, will result in an `out-channel` of size 3.