# How to use groups parameter in PyTorch conv2d function with batch?

Tags: pytorch

follow by the question in [How to use groups parameter in PyTorch conv2d function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536971/how-to-use-groups-parameter-in-pytorch-conv2d-function)

May I know if the input batch size = 4, for each batch it has independent filter to conv with it,  and I modify the code as follow,

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

filters = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3,4,3,3))
inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(4,3,10,10))
out = F.conv2d(inputs, filters, padding=1, groups=3)
```

I have another error
RuntimeError: Given groups=3, weight of size [3, 4, 3, 3], expected input[4, 3, 10, 10] to have 12 channels, but got 3 channels instead
How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

when you have filter of `shape (3,4,3,3)` then it is expected to have num of channels as 12

This should work

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3,12,10,10))
filters = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.randn(3,4,3,3))
out = F.conv2d(inputs, filters, padding=1, groups=3)
```

Comment: Assume that we a feature map, X, of size [4, 3, 10, 10] and a single kernel of size [3, 4, 1, 1]. When doing the vanilla convolution, we get a feature map of size [4, 1, 10, 10], while I’m after a way to get a feature map of size [4, 3, 10, 10]. I wanna conduct an elementwise multiplication by using conv2d.

Comment: @IvanLeung pls check the document about the dimension meanings before asking the questions https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#conv2d, what's more, for the elementwise multiplication you may just need simple * or torch.mul. just be careful about the rule of broadcast. https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that elementwise mul can be done by *. However, the snpe platform does not support * function. Hence, I need this tricks to make it work.