# What is the fastest way to use Pytorch Conv2d to apply multiple filters to every layer in multiple CT scans?

Tags: python, pytorch

Assume an input data set contains CT scans of 100 patients, each scan containing 16 layers and each layer containing 512 x 512 pixels.  I want to apply eight 3x3 convolution filters to each layer in every CT scan.  So, the input array has shape [100, 16, 512, 512] and the kernels array has shape [8, 3, 3].  After the convolutions are applied, the goal is an output array with a shape [100, 16, 8, 512, 512].  The following code uses Pytorch Conv2d function to achieve this; however, I want to know if the groups parameter (and/or other means) can somehow eliminate the need for the loop.

```
 for layer_index in range(0, number_of_layers):
    # Getting current ct scan layer for all patients
    # ct_scans dimensions are:  [patient, scan layer, pixel row, pixel column]
    # ct_scans shape: [100, 16, 512, 512]
    image_stack = ct_scans[:, layer_index, :, :]
    # Converting from numpy to tensor format
    image_stack_t = torch.from_numpy(image[:, None, :, :])
    # Applying convolution to create 8 filtered versions of current scan layer across all patients
    # shape of kernels is: [8, 3, 3]
    filtered_image_stack_t = conv2d(image_stack_t, kernels, padding=1, groups=1)
    # Converting from tensor format back to numpy format
    filtered_image_stack = filtered_image_stack_t.numpy()
    # Amassing filtered ct scans for all patients back into one array
    # filtered_ct_scans dimensions are: [patient, ct scan layer, filter number, pixel row, pixel column]
    # filtered_ct_scans shape is: [100, 16, 8, 512, 512]
    filtered_ct_scans[:, layer_index, :, :, :] = filtered_image_stack
```

So far, my attempts to use anything other than `groups=1` leads to errors.  I also found the following similar posts; however, they don't address my specific question.

[How to use groups parameter in PyTorch conv2d function with batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016678/how-to-use-groups-parameter-in-pytorch-conv2d-function-with-batch)

[How to use groups parameter in PyTorch conv2d function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536971/how-to-use-groups-parameter-in-pytorch-conv2d-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use grouped convolutions. Resizing you input appropriately is all that is needed.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

ct_scans = torch.randn((100,16,512,512))
kernels = torch.randn((8,1,3,3))

B,L,H,W = ct_scans.shape #(batch,layers,height,width)
ct_scans = ct_scans.view(-1,H,W)
ct_scans.unsqueeze_(1)
out = F.conv2d(ct_scans, kernels)
out = out.view(B,L,*out.shape[1:])
print(out)
```