# How can I make a filter in pytorch conv2d

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am really new to pytorch, and I've been making code convolution myself.

To apply convolution on input data, I use conv2d.

In the documentation,

```
torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size ...)
```

But where is a filter? To convolute, we should do it on input data with kernel. But there is only kernel size, not the elements of the kernel.

For example, There is an input data 5x5 and with 2x2 kernel with all 4 kernel's elements are 1 then I can make 4x4 output. So where can I put the elements of kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter weights can be accessed using the `weight` parameter of the `Conv2d` object. For example,

```
>>> c = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=2, out_channels=2, kernel_size=3)
>>> c.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[ 0.2156,  0.0930, -0.2319],
      [ 0.1333, -0.0846,  0.1848],
      [ 0.0765, -0.1799, -0.1273]],

     [[ 0.1173,  0.1650, -0.0876],
      [-0.1353,  0.0616, -0.1136],
      [-0.2326, -0.1509,  0.0651]]],


    [[[-0.2026,  0.2210,  0.0409],
      [-0.0818,  0.0793,  0.1074],
      [-0.1430, -0.0118, -0.2100]],

     [[-0.2025, -0.0508, -0.1731],
      [ 0.0217, -0.1616,  0.0702],
      [ 0.1903, -0.1864,  0.1523]]]], requires_grad=True)
```

The weights are initialized by default by [sampling from a uniform distribution](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html). You can also initialize weights using various [weight initialization schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49433936/5987698).

If you want to manually change the weights, you can do it by modifying the `weight` parameter directly. For example, to set all the weights to 1, use,

```
>>> c.weight.data = torch.ones_like(c.weight)
>>> c.weight
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.]],

     [[1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.]]],


    [[[1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.]],

     [[1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.],
      [1., 1., 1.]]]], requires_grad=True)
```

Note that during training, the convolutional layers are typically a part of the computational graph, and their weights get automatically updated when making a `backward()` call.

Comment: I got a question. Why are there 4 filters in c.weight? Only one is not enough?

Comment: @JAEMTO Because in the example I used, I set `in_channels=2` and `out_channels=2`. Each input channel is convolved to each output channel by default. To control this behaviour, you can modify the `groups` argument to `Conv2d`. (Some references: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46536971/5987698, https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html).

Comment: I got it and in conv2d, if the weights are initialized by default by sampling from a uniform distribution, then what is a diffrence from xavier uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [functional conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv2d.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) function, which takes an additional tensor of filters (as the argument `weights`).
The `nn.Conv2d` layer relies on this operation but handles the learning of the filters/weights automatically, which is generally more convenient